# The Huawei Account Kit is integrated into the my Harmony app. After the fingerprint is set, still get error code 6003

Tags: android, account, huawei-mobile-services, harmonyos, huawei-account

[image]

Error 6003 is reported when the API of the account kit is called for sign-in, and The certificate fingerprint has been configured on the AGC, still get error code 6003. Here's the log：

```
11-02 10:18:01.407 2876-4650/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: [nanotrace] Start tracing
11-02 10:18:01.407 2876-4637/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: jit_compiled:[OK] boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object) @ /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar
11-02 10:18:01.415 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[BridgeStubAbilityShellActivity]: handleWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus true inTouchMode true
11-02 10:18:01.415 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei W InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
11-02 10:18:01.423 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I HMSSDK_[AccountHos][ACCOUNTSDK]AccountSignInHubActivityStub: onActivityResult: requestCode：16587 , resultCode：6003
11-02 10:18:01.423 2876-4637/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: jit_compiled:[OK] void java.util.Calendar.updateTime() @ /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar
11-02 10:18:01.423 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I HMSSDK_[AccountHos][ACCOUNTSDK]AccountSignInHubActivityStub: onSignInAccountFailed: retCode：6003
11-02 10:18:01.424 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I HMSSDK_[AccountHos]MessageBus: enter publishMessage messageKey:signin
11-02 10:18:01.424 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I HMSSDK_[AccountHos]AccountAuthServiceAdapterImpl: signIn setreulst taskCompletionSource
11-02 10:18:01.424 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I HMSSDK_[AccountHos]AccountAuthUtil: getSignInResultFromIntent
11-02 10:18:01.427 2876-4637/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: jit_compiled:[OK] int libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getpid() @ /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar
11-02 10:18:01.428 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E EncryptUtil: getSecureRandomBytes: NoSuchAlgorithmException
11-02 10:18:01.428 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E SecurityComp10105306: AesGcmKS: alias or encrypt content is null
11-02 10:18:01.433 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I 01110/[AccountHos]HuaweiAccountSDKProxy: SignIn foreground FAILED.
11-02 10:18:01.433 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I 01110/[AccountHos]HuaweiAccountSDKProxy: SignIn foreground FAILED. status code: 6003.
11-02 10:18:01.432 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[BridgeStubAbilityShellActivity]: handleAppVisibility: mAppVisible false
11-02 10:18:01.433 2876-4637/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: jit_compiled:[OK] char android.util.HiLogFormatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(java.lang.String) @ /system/framework/hwEmui.jar
11-02 10:18:01.435 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E EncryptUtil: getSecureRandomBytes: NoSuchAlgorithmException
11-02 10:18:01.435 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E SecurityComp10105306: AesCbc: cbc encrypt param is not right
11-02 10:18:01.440 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E EncryptUtil: getSecureRandomBytes: NoSuchAlgorithmException
11-02 10:18:01.440 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E SecurityComp10105306: AesGcmKS: alias or encrypt content is null
11-02 10:18:01.441 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E EncryptUtil: getSecureRandomBytes: NoSuchAlgorithmException
11-02 10:18:01.441 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E SecurityComp10105306: AesCbc: cbc encrypt param is not right
11-02 10:18:01.443 2876-4637/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: jit_compiled:[OK] sun.misc.Cleaner sun.misc.Cleaner.add(sun.misc.Cleaner) @ /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar
11-02 10:18:01.449 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei E 01400/AGP_VIEW: notifyEditingTextChangeInternal mEditingCapability is null
11-02 10:18:01.449 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei E 01400/AGP_VIEW: notifyEditingTextChangeInternal mEditingCapability is null
11-02 10:18:01.450 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[BridgeStubAbilityShellActivity]: viewVisibilityChanged changed reason: viewVisibility change to invisible
11-02 10:18:01.451 2876-4659/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[HuaweiLoginAbilityShellActivity]: windowFocusChanged: hasFocus true inTouchMode true
11-02 10:18:01.451 2876-4659/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[BridgeStubAbilityShellActivity]: windowFocusChanged: hasFocus false inTouchMode true
11-02 10:18:01.452 2876-4689/com.example.hellohuawei W libEGL  : EGLNativeWindowType 0x708daa1490 disconnect failed
11-02 10:18:01.452 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[BridgeStubAbilityShellActivity]: relayoutWindow reason: viewVisibilityChanged = true
11-02 10:18:01.456 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[BridgeStubAbilityShellActivity]: relayoutWindow relayoutResult 5
11-02 10:18:01.457 2876-4637/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: jit_compiled:[OK] void java.lang.ref.Reference.<init>(java.lang.Object) @ /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar
11-02 10:18:01.459 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[HuaweiLoginAbilityShellActivity]: handleWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus true inTouchMode true
11-02 10:18:01.459 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei W InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
11-02 10:18:01.461 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[BridgeStubAbilityShellActivity]: handleWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus false inTouchMode true
11-02 10:18:01.462 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ActivityManager_activity: Reporting idle of ActivityRecord{2052cc8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@388391 {com.example.hellohuawei/com.example.hellohuawei.HuaweiLoginAbilityShellActivity}} finished=false
11-02 10:18:01.466 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E EncryptUtil: getSecureRandomBytes: NoSuchAlgorithmException
11-02 10:18:01.466 2876-4637/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: jit_compiled:[OK] org.json.JSONObject org.json.JSONObject.put(java.lang.String, int) @ /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar
11-02 10:18:01.466 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E SecurityComp10105306: AesGcmKS: alias or encrypt content is null
11-02 10:18:01.466 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E EncryptUtil: getSecureRandomBytes: NoSuchAlgorithmException
11-02 10:18:01.466 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E SecurityComp10105306: AesCbc: cbc encrypt param is not right
11-02 10:18:01.471 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E EncryptUtil: getSecureRandomBytes: NoSuchAlgorithmException
11-02 10:18:01.471 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E SecurityComp10105306: AesGcmKS: alias or encrypt content is null
11-02 10:18:01.471 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E EncryptUtil: getSecureRandomBytes: NoSuchAlgorithmException
11-02 10:18:01.471 2876-5448/com.example.hellohuawei E SecurityComp10105306: AesCbc: cbc encrypt param is not right
11-02 10:18:01.475 2876-4689/com.example.hellohuawei W libEGL  : EGLNativeWindowType 0x708daa1350 disconnect failed
11-02 10:18:01.566 2876-4637/com.example.hellohuawei I ple.hellohuawe: jit_compiled:[OK] int java.lang.String.indexOf(java.lang.String) @ /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar
11-02 10:18:01.697 2876-2876/com.example.hellohuawei I ViewRootImpl[AccountSignInHubStubAbilityShellActivity]: handleAppVisibility: mAppVisible false
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature certificate of the HarmonyOS application is different from the signature certificate of the Android application.

The signature certificate of the HarmonyOS application is a **.p12** file. Like following:

[image]

You could check the signature certificate fingerprint as follows:

[image]